# Root form of the for mod $p^n$(Hensel theorem.)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let the $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $p$ be a prime number

For $f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod p$, Say "$\alpha$" be a root of the $f$ for $mod$ $p$ with $(f'(\alpha),p)=1$, Surely $0 \leq \alpha < p $

Then Does $f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod {p^{n+1}}$ also have the  root as a "$\alpha$" for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

In my guess it would be a wrong statment because $f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod {p^{n+1}}$ has a root among $\alpha + tp^n$ for $mod p^n$ for $0 \leq t \leq p-1 $. Hence there are other possibilities that roots is $\alpha + tp^n$($0 < t \leq p-1$) , So we can't sure that the roots is $\alpha$ for $mod p^{n+1}$

But my problem is I don't have a confidence my guess is right or not. because  couldn't find any counterexample. Is my guess right?

Any answer would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: It does not necessarily have $\alpha$ as a root; but it does have a root that is congruent to $\alpha$ modulo $p$. Hensel’s Lemma guarantees that exactly one of the lifts will be a root, and it gives you a formula for computing it, but you cannot guarantee it is always the same one. In fact, it won’t unless $f(x)$ has $\alpha$ as a root in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that you cannot guarantee that $\alpha$ will be a root modulo $p^n$. Here’s an example:

Consider $f(x) = x^2+1$ and $p=5$. Then $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{5}$ has a $\alpha=2$ as a root. And since $f’(x) = 2x$ with $f’(\alpha)\not\equiv 0\pmod{5}$, this root lifts to a root modulo $5^2$; but the root modulo $5^2$ is not $\alpha=2$, it is $7=\alpha+5$; this is the only root modulo $25$ that is congruent to $\alpha$ modulo $2$.

This problems persists even if you allow $\alpha$ to take an arbitrary value, and not merely a value between $0$ and $p$. To see this, assume that $\alpha$ is any integer with $f(\alpha)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. If $n$ is such that $\alpha^2+1\lt 5^n$, then we cannot have $f(\alpha)\equiv 0\pmod{5^{n+1}}$, as that would require $5^{n+1}$ to divide $\alpha^2+1$, but $0\lt \alpha^2+1\lt 5^{n+1}$, which is impossible. Thus, at some point, you will have to change the $\alpha$ to get a solution modulo $5^n$.

You can do better using $p$-adic numbers. The sequence $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n,\ldots)$ of integers that are consistent solutions to $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p^n}$ (that is, $f(\alpha_i)\equiv 0\pmod{p^i}$, and $\alpha_{i+1}\equiv \alpha_i\pmod{p^i}$) defines a $p$-adic number that is a solution to $f(x)=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. The sequence is eventually constant if and only if the sequence defines an integer (an element that is an image of an integer under the canonical embedding $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Z}_p$). In particular, the sequence is eventually constant if and only if that limit is in fact an integer root for $f(x)$.